# Qual o termo que melhor se encaixa como tradução de "generative AI"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, neologismos, norma-culta

Vejo na mídia o termo "Inteligencia artificial *generativa*" sendo usado.

Contudo, o neologismo me soa áspero e estranho. Não seria melhor "gerativa" ou "geradora" para estes modelos que criam imagens e conversas?

De acordo com a norma culta, qual o termo que deveríamos usar, ignorando a pressão da imprensa?

Comment: Por uma vez que as palavras são as mesmas....

Comment: Os termos são criados pelas pessoas do campo. Tipo, "Ei, João! Isto é uma I.A. que gera coisa. Estou chamando de 'I.A. generativa' para facilitar." Não há regra. Num mesmo artigo de matemática, toda hora se inventa um termo. Então, desde que a pessoa saiba ao que você se refere, pode usar qualquer coisa... "Inteligência artificial geradora".

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade não se trata de um neologismo.
O termo já consta, por exemplo, no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/generativo):

> 1. Que gera ou tem a propriedade de gerar.
> 2. [Linguística] Que é capaz de gerar o conjunto infinito das frases de uma língua por meio da aplicação de um conjunto finito de regras.

Em que fica claro que "generativo" não apenas pode atuar como um sinônimo dos termos "gerador" e "gerativo", como também tem um significado técnico na linguística.

Outros dicionários também contém o termo: [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/generativo/), Houaiss, [TheFreeDictionary](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/generativo), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/generativo), [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/generativo), [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/generativo/), o [*Novo Diccionário da Língua Portuguesa*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31552) por Candido de Figueiredo, Lisboa, 1913:

[image: Verbete "generativo": Relativo a geração; que póde gerar. (Do la. generare)]

e o [*Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza Recopilado, Tomo Segundo*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Diccionario_de_lingua_portuguesa/GI8MAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA84&printsec=frontcover) de Antonio de Moraes Silva, Lisboa, 1813:

[image]

Quanto à questão central, sobre se "generativo" seria a melhor tradução, veja a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9901/2764) do bad_coder.

Comment: Claro, seria o mais óbvio, né?

Comment: Que o termo consta nos dicionarios online, fáceis de se editar e com grande interesse em se manterem atuais e relevantes, não é surpresa. Portanto, este fato tem pouco peso ao se classificar a palavra como neologismo ou não.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica Seria improvável que todos esses dicionários se atualizassem tão rápido mas, por via das dúvidas, adicionei referências a obras mais antigas que já continham o verbete.

Comment: Há uma diferença de sentido entre "linguística generativa" (que é a teoria linguistica iniciada por Noam Chomsky - há inclusive diferenças de opinião sobre se gerativo ou generativo é o termo mais correcto) e o sentido de generativo como é usado na inteligência artificial.

Comment: @bad_coder Sim, eu percebi. Por isso também não opino sobre qual termo seria o melhor aqui, só que não se trata de um neologismo usado devido à "pressão da imprensa".

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica o termo na linguística e informática já tem 60 anos e desde logo estabeleceu-se como um termo dominante no campo científico, portanto os dicionários não podiam ficar meio século sem oferecer uma definição. Sobre as razões da preferência por uma palavra em vez da outra dei uma resposta com alguns dos critérios que terão pesado na escolha.

Answer (score 1):

Responder à questão exige uma perspectiva etimológica e morfológica.

Ao confrontar *generativo* com *gerativo* estamos a lidar com **radicais diferentes**! Vamos separar a desinência do infinitivo da forma citacional do verbo *gerar* e o sufixo de *generativo* para evidenciar os radicais:

> **ger**-ar
>
> Priberam Origem etimológica gero, -are.
> Enquanto para:

> **gener**-a-tivo
>
> Priberam Origem etimológica francês génératif.

Se formos ver os dicionários ingleses em geral a origem é apresentada como incerta entre o latim e o francês,

> [Oxford English dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/generative_adj?tl=true)
> generative is of multiple origins. Either (i) a borrowing from French. Or (ii) a borrowing from Latin.
>
> Etymons: French generatif; Latin generativus.
> O [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/generative) dicionário etimológico justifica a diferença por ambiguidade do sufixo **-ive** que pode ser do francês ou adaptado do latim.

---

Em qualquer caso, o radical **gener**(-ativo) pode não parecer ser um radical opaco em português, porque coincide com o radical (nominal) da palavra **géner**-o nossa conhecida. Mas aqui econtramos o primeiro problema, o **radical verbal** **gener**-ar é de facto um radical opaco em português, e uma prova disso é o sufixo **-tivo** na nossa lingua ser necessariamente **deverbal**, ou seja: só deriva de bases verbais!

Não exista um verbo **gener**-ar, mas recuperamos o mesmo radical (verbal) no verbo [re-**gener**-ar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/regenerar) ou de-**gener**-ar que também reconhecemos. Portanto o radical verbal é opaco mas o radical nominal não o é. O radical verbal **gener**(-ar) por si está indisponível para formação de novas palavras na sincronia. (Notem que o segmento -a- entre o radical e o sufixo em gener-**a**-tivo é o chamado *"tema do grupo do presente"* que o sufixo seleciona até hoje em português).

As palavras acima tem a mesma raiz, como podemos ver do latim para [gĕnĕro](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn19424,do117) -> [rĕ-gĕnĕro](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn40880) mas são distintos do radical [gĕro](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn19512,lsn19513,do22,do193) de **ger**(-ar). (Não consigo perceber se tem uma raiz comum no latim *genus* mas mesmo que tenham esse facto é exterior à morfologia do português.)

Há portanto boas razões para não devermos considerar as palavras *gener-ativo* e *ger-ativo* intercambiáveis:

1. A semântica é próxima, mas as propriedades morfológicas são muito diferentes.
2. Um dos radicais é opaco e portanto indisponível.
3. Lendo os autores dos campos científicos -seja o campo linguístico ou informático- vemos que foi adoptado pela maioria *generativo*.

Sendo o *generativo* um conceito científico tornou-se parte de **nome próprio composto**. Faz por isso sentido aproveitar a palavra já existente nos dicionários portugueses há pelo menos 200 anos (como a resposta do Stafusa acima bem demonstrou) e **assim evitar a introdução de um termo que fosse diferir ainda mais no radical da literatura estrangeira!**

Embora, naturalmente, isto possa suscitar dúvidas ao falante que vai interrogar-se sobre se um ou outro radical é o mais correcto e qual a diferença entre eles.